# "int is incompatible with date", when adding date via VB to SQL server

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using the below code to insert a date into my SQL dB, but I keep getting the error.

"Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date"

Here is my code:

```
Using cmdb = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tarrifs (Tarrif, Created_Date) VALUES (@tarrif2, @DateTime)", con)
con.Open()
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarrif2", TextBox1.Text)
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", SqlDbType.Date)
cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
End Using
End Using
```

I think it is because SQL is reading it as a literal string and not a date.

Can anyone help with the correct syntax?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: `SqlDbType.Date` is a member of an enum called `SqlDbType` which is based on `int`. You're calling `AddWithValue`, you presumable intended to supply a value there, or to call `Add` (with the overload that expects an `SqlDbType`) and to set the `Value` separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SqlDbType` is an enum. You're trying to use one of its values (`SqlDbType.Date`) which is `int` as parameter value. You need to supply a `DateTime` value instead:

```
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", YourDateTimeVariable)
```

---

If you try to add current date and time, you don't need to supply it from the code, you can:

use DateTime.Now():

```
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now());
```

or use `GETDATE()` function from SQL Server:

```
Using cmdb = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tarrifs (Tarrif, Created_Date) VALUES (@tarrif2, GETDATE())", con)
    con.Open()
    cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarrif2", TextBox1.Text)
    cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, whats the correct variable for current date?

Comment: @user3580480 I cannot tell you but what date do you need? Current date and time maybe as you're inserting it into CreatedDate?

Comment: I am trying to add TODAYS date as variable

Comment: @user3580480 try datetime.now()

Comment: +1 @user3580480 cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now()) did the trick

Comment: @user3580480 Then show the dude some love and accept the answer and upvote!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've not supplied a date value for the @DateTime parameter.  You've specified a datatype, which is a integer.

Thanks